# How to derive the size of a simple bias in a mediation setting?

Tags: r, causality, mediation, confounding, dag

Consider the following DAG which shows the direct and indirect effect of $U$ on $Y$.

The total effect of $U \rightarrow Y$ is simply $(2\times4) + 3 = 11$.

I am looking for the derivation of the **biased** effect of $A \rightarrow Y$.

When I run simulation I get a biased effect of about 5.5

How can I retrieve mathematically this 5.5?

[image]

```
# R simulation

n = 100000
u = rnorm(n, 0, 1)
a = u*2

y = 3*u + 4*a

lm(y ~ a) # biased effect
lm(y ~ u) # total effect
lm(y ~ a + u) # correct effects
```

---

2 ways to compute the bias effect, which is what I observe from the simulation, I worked out but that do not make sense to me why it works. Is there a general formula to compute expected bias?

1. Divide the total effect of $U$ on $Y$, by the path $U \rightarrow A$, $\frac{11}{2}=5.5$
2. Let's label the paths: $U \rightarrow A = a$, $A \rightarrow Y = b$, and $U \rightarrow Y = c$, then we can compute the bias with: a + ($\frac{c}{b}$), $4 + \frac{3}{2} = 5.5$

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. I would have expected the biased effect to be simply $7=3+4.$ It's certainly true that the total effect of $U$ on $Y$ is correct, and that if you want the unbiased effect of $A$ on $Y$, you must include $U$ in the regression to correct for the confounder.

Comment: strange no? I had the same intuition as you but then I started working out example and it didn't worked! Look at my two solutions and see if you can make sense why they work.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I can follow the theoretical reason why your solutions produce $5.5.$ Why divide by $a=2$ anywhere? +1, by the way, simply for including a DAG.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, the result 5.5 is the result from the simulation. I just can't find a general formula about how to compute expected bias in a simple setting like this.

Comment: Right. I'm afraid I don't have any explanations, either. I agree that $5.5$ appears to be the simulation values (I copied your code and ran it myself and got the same results you did.) But I don't have a theoretical explanation of why $5.5$ should be the result.

Comment: I found this strange because it seems really useful to me to be able to predict bias for a given DAG.

Comment: @AdrianKeister check my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OLS coefficient is the ratio of covariance to variance. That is, let
$$
y = \beta a + \nu.
$$

Then $\beta = \frac{Cov (y,a)}{Var(a)} = \frac{Cov(11u,2u)}{Var(2u)} = \frac{22}{4} \frac{Var(u)}{Var(u)} = 5.5$.

(We can skip the intercept as both variables have mean 0)

More details for example here: https://jrnold.github.io/intro-methods-notes/regression-anatomy.html

Comment: Nice one too thanks. Could you have a look at my solution too? I was just more thinking of it in mediation term. Thanks

Comment: @giac Keeping things in line with your notation, we have in general $a = \alpha \cdot u$ and $y = \delta u + \beta a$. So the covariance formula from above implies  $ \frac{Cov(\delta u + \beta \cdot \alpha u,\alpha u)}{Var(\alpha u)} = \frac{ (\delta + \beta \alpha)\alpha}{\alpha^2} = \frac{\delta}{\alpha} + \beta$, which is the same as your answer. So your approach is correct, I think.

Answer (score 2):

We start with this

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
U &= 1 \\
X &= 2 U \\
Y &= 3 U + 4 X \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Re-arranging the equation we can derive the bias like this (we can call $X'$ the biased effect of $X$)

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Y &= 3 U + 4 X \\
Y - 4 X &= 3 U \\
Y - 4 \underbrace{X}_{2U} &= 3 U \\
Y - 4 \times 2 U &= 3 U \\
Y - 4 &= \frac{3 U}{2 U} \\
Y  &= 4 +  1.5  \\
Y  &= 5.5 X' \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

We could derive a formula with a general DAG like this

[image]

\begin{equation}
Y = \beta + \frac{\delta}{\alpha}
\end{equation}

We can theoretically predict the size of a spurious association in a DAG like this with this formula

[image]

$\beta=0$

\begin{equation}
Y = \frac{4}{2} X'
\end{equation}

It works!

```
n = 1000
u = rnorm(n, 0, 1)
x = 2*u + rnorm(n, 0, 0.01)
y = 4*u + rnorm(n, 0, 0.01)

lm(y~x)
# Spurious association of 2!
```